# How can I make a SharePoint site responsive?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I will have a test task, and I only know that I'll have some limited time to design a page in the classic mode of SharePoint Online. The task is also to make a page responsive to other devices.

Should I use HTML responsive meta tags with media queries in SP Designer? Is it possible to do it quickly, or it will require a lot of time? Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any chance this assignment is a kind of trick question in order to see if you will do as told or let the requestor know that it is bad idea?
Classic is not very resposive and I guess MS would have provided a better solution if it was posible.
Actually they have done that in the modern version so why the request to do it in classic when modern is responsive out of the box...